# Como implementar o algoritmo Dijkstra em Pascal?

Tags: pascal

Estou a tentar implementar o algoritmo de Dijkstra, criando uma função em Pascal.

Tenho algo como:

```
function Dijkstra(L:mapa):integer;
begin
   min := max ;
   map.mini:= 0;
   for i := 2 to min do
      if L.matriz[i,j] < map.mini then
         begin
            min:= L.matriz[i,j];
            map.mini := i;
         end;
      Dijkstra:=map.mini ;
end;
```

Até onde cheguei não está a funcionar, alguma sugestão?

Comment: Esse seu algoritmo não está muito parecido com o de [Dijkstra](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Dijkstra)...

Comment: E a qual dos algoritmos de Dijkstra vc se refere?

Comment: preciso de este aqui 


função Dijkstra(L = [1..n, 1..n]: grafo): vetor[2..n]
C := {2,3,...,n} 
Para i := 2 até n:
D[i] :=   L[1,i] 
P[i] :=   1 
Repetir n-2 vezes:
v :=   Elemento de C que minimiza D[v] 
C :=   C - {v} 
Para cada elemento w de C:
Se D[w] > D[v]+ L[v,w] então
D[w] :=   D[v]+ L[v,w] 
P[w] := v
Retornar P

Answer (score 1):

**Encontrei essa resposta no livro PASCAL ESTRUTURADO 3

  Edição Editora LTC 1999

Dos autores :

Harry Farrer

Christiano Gonçaves Becker

Eduardo Chaves Faria

...**

**Exemplo 2.27 página 77..**

Os nós no gráfico apresentado a seguir representam as cidades e os arcos a presença de uma estrada ligando duas cidades os números ao lado dos Arcos representa a distância em quilômetros.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pode se representar,numericamente, este grafo por uma variável composta bidimensional ,na qual a distância entre duas cidades i,j é indicado pelo elemento D(i,j; se i=j  ou se não houver conexão entre i e i. D(i.i) será zero. Dessa forma tem-se:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema consiste, então, em se achar  o caminho mais curto entre duas cidades quaisquer. Este problema foi resolvido por Dijkistra [DIJKISTRA, 1971] e tem uma série de aplicação de questões de otimização.
Além da matriz  D das distâncias, considera-se a variável composta  unidimensional DA,
cuja componente DA[I] representa a distância acumulada  em um  caminho percorrido  desde a 
origem até a cidade I. Cada uma destas componentes será iniciada com um valor bem grande, por exemplo 10000.

Ainda serão consideradas mais duas variáveis compostas unidimensionais. A primeira, designada Ant, será tal que a sua componente Ant[I] indica qual é a cidade antecedente de I no caminho considerado. A  outra ExpA, terá componentes lógicas "expandidas".
 Partindo de uma cidade C inicialmente igual a origem, calcula-se a nova distância acumulada (NovaDA) de cada uma das cidades adjacentes a C ainda não expandidas. A nova distância acumulada prevalecerá sobre o valor anterior se lhe for inferior, neste caso ,C será atribuído a  componente Ant[I]. Quando terminar a expansão de C, registra-se que ExpA[C] é verdadeiro.
  Em seguida, procura-se, dentre as cidades ainda não expandidas, aquelas que têm a menor distancia acumulada. Esta será  a nova cidade C,  e a sua distancia acumulada é, então, a menor que possa ser conseguida  a partir  da Origem.
  O processo será repetido até que a cidade C  seja o Destino  ou que não se encontre nenhuma cidade ainda não expandida, cuja distancia acumulada seja inferior  a 10000. Neste último caso, isto significa que não existe caminho ligando a Origem ao Destino.

Aqui esta o algoritmo em linguagem pascal:

```
program Dijkistra;

var D: array[1..100, 1..100] of integer;
    DA, Ant: array[1..100] of integer;
    ExpA: array[1..100] of boolean;
    N, Origem, Destino, I, J, C, NovaDA, Min: integer;

begin
   readln(N);
   for I:= 1 to N do
   begin
       for J:= 1 to N do
       read(D[I,J]);
       readln;
   end;
  readln(Origem, Destino); { atribuição de valores iniciais necessários}
    for I:= 1 to N do
        begin
            ExpA[I]:= false;
            DA[I]:= 10000
        end;
    C:= origem;
    DA[C]:= 0;
    while (C <> Destino) and(C <> 0) do
   begin {Expanção de C}
    for I:= 1 to N do
    if (D[C, I] <> 0) and(not Expa[i])
    then begin
            NovaDA:= DA[C] + D[C, I];
            if NovaDA < DA[I] 
            then begin
                   DA[I]:= NovaDA;
                   Ant[I]:= C
                  end
         end;
    Expa[C]:= true; {Determinação do proximo C}
    Min:= 10000;
    C:= 0;
    for I:= 1 to N do
    if (not ExpA[I]) and (DA[I] < Min)
    then
       begin
            Min:= DA[I];
            C:= I;
        end;
    end;

    if C = Destino
    then begin
            writeln('Caminho mais curto');
            writeln(C);
            while C <> Origem do
                begin
                    C:= Ant[C];
                    writeln(C)
                end
          end
     else writeln('Não existe caminho unindo as duas cidades');
end.
```

Comment: Você está transcrevendo o livro do Harry Farrer. Ok, tudo bem fazer isso, mas [é obrigatório citar a fonte](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1772).

Comment: Como assim? Eu não tenho a referência do livro! Use o link de editar que está logo abaixo da sua resposta e coloque a referência. Recomendo também deixar claro o que é texto seu e o que é transcrição do livro (pode usar `>` no começo da linha para formatar como citação).